# Python Selenium - Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium

I just started learning selenium and I'm facing some issues with some code that should be quite easy to write..

I'm simply trying to enter "Paris" in the input field, but I keep getting the error: "Unable to locate element". Do I need to refer to the div tag or the input tag in order for it to work?

Here's my code at the moment.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# Setup webdriver
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

# Open website maximized
driver.get("https://www.corsair.ca/")
driver.maximize_window()
print(driver.title)

# Select and enter destination
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Votre destination']"))).click()

to_city = driver.find_element_by_class_name("form-control valid")
to_city.send_keys("Paris")
to_city.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Here's the error I have

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\FlightFinder\venv\SeleniumTutorial.py", line 26, in <module>
   to_city = driver.find_element_by_class_name("form-control valid")
   File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\FlightFinder\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
   return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
   File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\FlightFinder\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
   return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
   File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\FlightFinder\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
   self.error_handler.check_response(response)
   File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\FlightFinder\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
   raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".form-control valid"}
   (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.183)
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error output.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".form-control valid"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.183)

Comment: Could you add the full error? The stack trace in the comments does not include the line number

Comment: Sorry about that. I added it to the original post.